# mysql select latest date with multiple results

Tags: mysql, database

I have one table named DETAILS with details:

```
CODE | NAME    | ENTRY-DATE | NEXT-ENTRY-DATE
A001 | Adam    | 2010-01-01 | 2010-05-01
B001 | Bob     | 2010-11-01 | 2012-02-11
C001 | Charlie | 2010-01-01 | 2010-02-01
D001 | Dexton  | 2010-01-01 | 2013-12-11
A001 | Adam    | 2010-05-01 | 2013-05-15
B001 | Bob     | 2012-02-11 | 2013-02-11
```

what I want the results is:

```
CODE | NAME    | ENTRY-DATE | NEXT-ENTRY-DATE
C001 | Charlie | 2010-01-01 | 2010-02-01
D001 | Dexton  | 2010-01-01 | 2013-12-11
A001 | Adam    | 2010-05-01 | 2013-05-15
B001 | Bob     | 2012-02-11 | 2013-02-11
```

What I want to take is the latest entry for each code. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676273/select-distinct-where-date-is-max#21676273

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470311/get-the-latest-date-from-grouped-mysql-data

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM details GROUP BY code;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using max() will ensure that the value you get is right:

```
SELECT CODE, NAME, MAX(ENTRY-DATE), NEXT-ENTRY-DATE
FROM DETAILS
GROUP BY CODE;
```